# Scrolling to Li Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to automate a scrolling bar in a fixed div constructed with UL and LI elements. I found this suggestion `$('#yourUL').scrollTop($('#yourUL li:nth-child(#)').position().top);` but it is not working for me.

```
<div class="download-section">
   ...
   <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
      <ul class="list-group" id="ulid">
         <?php include 'myextraction.php';?>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
      $('#ulid').scrollTop($('#ulid li:nth-child(#)').position().top);
   </script>
   ...
</div>
```

My "li"s are order by ascending date (the more recent is at the bottom).
I want to automatically scrollTo the next li given the date.
Eg today is 26th December, and the next event is the 31th January. Hence I want to scrollTo the li corresponding to the 31th January

https://jsfiddle.net/jojo1994/g0nmye8m/

Comment: Can you build a fiddle with the way it looks now?

Comment: You're missing a space between de ID and the ```li```: ```#ulid li:nth-child(#)```

Answer (score 1):

You were selecting `ul` tag whereas your `parent div` has an `overflow-y` which adds scrollbar on content overflow, so change your selector from `#ulid` to `.panel-body`.

**From**

```
$('#ulid').scrollTop($('ul > li:nth-child(#)').position().top);
```

**To**

```
$('.panel-body').scrollTop($('ul > li:nth-child(2)').position().top);
```

```js
 $('.panel-body').scrollTop($('ul > li:nth-child(2)').position().top);
```

```css
.panel-body > ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.panel-body > ul > li{
  padding:50px 0px;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
      <ul class="list-group" id="ulid">
        <li>Date - 5/12/2017</li>
        <li>Date - 15/12/2017</li>
        <li>Date - 23/12/2017</li>
        <li>Date - 25/12/2017</li>
        <li>Date - 26/12/2017</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: It won't scroll automatically to the next date, you need to change the nth-child() for targeted date.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you:

```js
 for(var i=2010; i<2250; i++){
    $('#ulid').append('<li id="'+i+'">'+i+'</li>');
}



function go(){
    var val= 2017;
    var y = prompt("Go where?", val);
    $('.panel-body').scrollTop($('#ulid #'+y).position().top - 2 * $('#ulid #'+y).height());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
<div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
  <ul class="list-group" id="ulid">
     
  </ul>
   </div>
```